# Implement heap using stack data structure

Tags: algorithms, heaps, stacks

I want to implement a heap using the stack data structure. I have searched a lot on the internet. But I do not get any clue how to implement it.

Can you please help me to implement a heap using the stack data structure? The pseudo-code is well enough. I can implement the rest.

Comment: Sounds more challenging than the other way around. Please add, for the purpose of this question, the operations *stack* provides as well as those required from *heap*. Add *property requirements* as needed.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I'm finding it hard to see why you wouldn't just implement a heap as a heap or in an array, unless it's a homework exercise.

Comment: It is previous admission test question of my university which I want to solve

Comment: Please mention which heap operations need to be implemented and which stack operations are available.  It might not be possible to implement all the standard min-heap operations (including insert) if only one stack is available for storage.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit vague on the meaning of "using the stack data structure" but I'm going to take an educated guess on a possible implementation. I'll also be assuming that we are interested in a min-heap, that the stack support the push, pop, and top operations, and that the min-heap should support the make-heap, push, pop, and top operations.

The data structure consists of single stack $S$ that will contain the elements of the heap.

**Make-heap$(A)$**: To build a heap from a set of elements $A$, sort $A$ in *nonincreasing* order and push the elements one by one into $S$ (according to their order). In this way the last element to be pushed into the stack will be one of the minimums of $A$. This requires $O(|A| \log |A|)$ time.

**Top**: Return the top element of $S$ (in $O(1)$ time).

**Pop**: Pop the top element $x$ from $S$ (in $O(1)$ time). Return $x$.

**Push$(x)$:** To push a new element $x$ into the min-heap proceed as follows: create a new temporary stack $T$; while the top element $y$ of $S$ is smaller than $x$, pop $y$ from $S$ and push it into $T$; Finally, push $x$ into $S$ and iteratively pop the elements from $T$ while pushing them into $S$. When $T$ is empty you are done. Sadly, this requires $O(|S|)$ time in the worst case.